# React useContext getting undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, createcontext

there is a simple codesandbox example [https://codesandbox.io/s/red-butterfly-kz13ee?file=/src/userName.jsx:0-270][1]

I have two components first one is a surname and the second one is a username where I have a greeting and trying to import the last name from component -> surname but getting undefined

---

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">

import {createContext, useState} from 'react'

export const lastNameContext = createContext()

const Surname = () => {

  const [lastName, setLastName]= useState('Smith')

  return (<lastNameContext.Provider value={lastName}>
    <h1>{lastName}</h1>
    </lastNameContext.Provider>)

}

export default Surname ;



</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js">

import { useContext} from 'react'
import FirstName from './FirstName'
import Surname, {lastNameContext} from './Surname'


const UserName = () => {
  const lastName = useContext(lastNameContext);
  return (<><h1>{`Hello: ${lastName}`}</h1></>)
}

export default UserName

</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting undefined.

Comment: The component that consumes the context must be wrapped by the context provider. I don't see `UserName` being wrapped by it anywhere in the example you're providing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `<h1>{lastName}</h1>` in your `Surname` component with `<UserName />`

Comment: Hi, Chad It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Basic usage of context

```
export const lastNameContext = createContext()

// context value provider
const SurnameContext = (props) => {

  const [lastName, setLastName]= useState('Smith')

  // all children of this component will be able to use the context value

  return (
    <lastNameContext.Provider value={lastName}>
       {props.children}
    </lastNameContext.Provider>)

 // return (<lastNameContext.Provider value={lastName} {...props} />))

}
```

using context on children

```
const UserName = () => {

  const lastName = useContext(lastNameContext);

  return (<><h1>{`Hello: ${lastName}`}</h1></>)
}


// parent providing the children with context
const DisplayNameWithContext  = (props) => {
    return (
        <SurnameContext> 
           // any component at any level will be able to use 
           //   const lastName = useContext(lastNameContext);
           <UserName {...props} />
        </SurnameContext>
    )
}
```

You read the new React docs [about context](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context), they will definately help you, Cheers